# Enable button after writing file to response

Tags: c#, asp.net

There is many similar questions but there is still no clear answer that is solving the problem taking some action after writing some stream to response.

I have a following situation:

On button click I am generating some excel file that I am going to write to response allowing user to download generated file. Imidietly after clicking the button, I am disabling it, to prevent double clicking this button. In Page-Load event handler I have following code:

```
 GenerateBTN.Attributes.Add("onclick", "this.disabled=true;" + ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(GenerateBTN, "").ToString());
```

After Page_Load eventhandler, GenerateBTN_Click handler executes the code needed for generating the file and at the end of this method (handler) I am response writing generated file with following code:

```
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";                
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + filename + "\"");
Response.WriteFile(@"C:\Reports\" + filename);
Response.End();
```

The Save As dialog appears and user can download the generated file, but the problem is that the disabled GenerateBTN remains disabled. How to enable it afer Writing generated file to response? I understand that afer clearing current response I can not continue with the initial Response, but is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: Enabling button with a few seconds delay in javascript could be an acceptable hack here. Note that 2 code snippets in the questoin are executed in different instances of the page; 2nd response is not even HTML and can't affect original page in any way. It's still possible to make them interact, but it will involve additional elements and more code, e.g. you can re-enable that button via AJAX.

Answer (score 1):

You can put an IFrame on the page and set it's visiblity to hidden.  Have your button load the file in the IFrame and use Javascript to detect if the IFrame is still loading or not.  When the loading is done, enable your button.

Can't supply a code example at the moment, but if you decide to go this route and need a sample, let me know I will update this answer.

**Edit for 2nd answer**

What you want to do is create a file like "Download.aspx" that you pass in the file name as a querystring parameter.  This way, you can have your server get the file from a location outside of the Web Application's path and adjust the header to force a file download.

***Download.aspx***

> ```
>   using System.IO;
> ```

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string FileName = Server.UrlDecode(Request.Params["FileName"]);  //Example: "MyFile.txt"

        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Type", "application/force-download");
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + FileName);
        Response.WriteFile(@"C:\MyFolder\" + FileName);
    }
```

You would load the page by calling something like "Download.aspx?FileName=MyFile.txt"

You will need to add checks to make sure the file exists and the querystring parameter exists, but that should force the download and allow you to get the file from another location.  When you use an ASPX page to serve the file, you can also do credential checks to see if the user is logged into your site (if you have login logic already) or log the download to a log file/database if you want to keep track of it.  It gives you a lot more control over the download process.

As for the IFrame loading code, I'm not 100% sure how this works with a file download, but what I was originally thinking was something like this -- view source on: http://sykari.net/stuff/iframe.

Comment: Can you look at my last answer? I haven't put it in comment because of characters limitation...

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the button in an UpdatePanel, then simply toggle its enabled property before and after the file work.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't output both a file and HTML (etc) to the browser in the same response.  I think he still needs to send the file or javascript using a separate frame...

Answer (score 0):

> You can put an IFrame on the page and
>   set it's visiblity to hidden. Have
>   your button load the file in the
>   IFrame and use Javascript to detect if
>   the IFrame is still loading or not.
>   When the loading is done, enable your
>   button.
>
> Can't supply a code example at the
>   moment, but if you decide to go this
>   route and need a sample, let me know I
>   will update this answer.

I've decided to use your suggestion.. but i still have some questions regarding this problem...
Is it possible to load .txt files in iframe?
Is it possible to load some files that are not included in web application's folder?

The problem with loading txt files in iframe is it does not trigger save as dialog to appear, instead of that file content is displayed inside that iframe.

For loading files into an iframe I've used following code:

```
HiddenFrame.Attributes["src"] = /GeneratedFiles/ + "test.zip";
```

You can see that I've had to use relative path and my file has to be included in web app's virtual folder.

What is the best javascript (jquery) eventhandler (function) to detect when Iframe has finished loading? I've used jquery function:

```
 $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_HiddenFrame").ready(function () {

        if ($("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_HiddenFrame").attr('src') != '') {

            $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_GenerateSapFilesBTN').removeAttr("disabled");
        }
    });
```

But it appears that button is being enabled before Save As dialog actually appears.. Is it possible to solve this problem with this type of eventHandler or do I have to use some other function...